# Do Core Data derived attributes work properly with Cloudkit?

Tags: core-data

In my use case I have two entities `List` and `Item` that have an optional one to many relationship. I would like to have two non transient derived attributes on `List`: `items.@count` and `items.@sum`. Does this work?

For this to work, I think core data would have to recompute these attributes whenever the list record or a related item record is received by a device from Cloudkit. Does CoreKit do this?

If this doesn't happen automatically can I make it work? Perhaps I can use NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey to check each incoming `List` and `Item` and compute the true count and sum, compare them to what's in the latest `List`entity, and update the `List` entity if it's wrong. This seems likely to result in a lot of pingponging updates and conflicts though.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question. Here is the code that demonstrates how to achieve derived attributes with Core Data and CloudKit:

```swift
import CoreData
import CloudKit

// Assuming you have List and Item entities with a one-to-many relationship

// List entity
class List: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var items: Set<Item>
    @NSManaged var itemCount: Int16
    @NSManaged var itemSum: Double
}

// Item entity
class Item: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var value: Double
}

// In your CoreData stack setup, enable history tracking
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
description.cloudKitContainerOptions = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: "your.container.id")
description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)

// Whenever you update related Item records in Core Data, recalculate derived attributes
func updateDerivedAttributes(for list: List) {
    let itemCount = list.items.count
    let itemSum = list.items.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1.value })
    
    list.itemCount = Int16(itemCount)
    list.itemSum = itemSum
    
    // Save your managedObjectContext to persist changes
}

// CloudKit subscription to monitor changes and trigger updates
let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "List", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
let notificationInfo = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

// Add the subscription to your CloudKit database
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "your.container.id")
let database = container.privateCloudDatabase
database.save(subscription) { subscription, error in
    // Handle subscription save completion
}
```

Keep in mind that using derived attributes with CloudKit can introduce complexities, especially with syncing and conflicts. You may need to carefully manage updates to avoid excessive conflicts. The approach using `NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey` could work but might indeed result in conflicts if updates are frequent. Consider using conflict resolution strategies if needed.

Comment: Thank you!. Doesn't CKQuerySubscription only fire for changes coming from cloudkit, meaning this won't update the derived attributes for changes initiated locally? In this example where should updateDerivedAttributes be called?